# Disable a Spinner Value?

Tags: android

How to Disable a Spinner Value?

Comment: why u want to show disable spinner value remove it

Comment: K..thks actully i have to make lots of chnges to remove that,so i was thinking of a short way..Lolzz ..thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to disable specific values in Spinner. Instead you have to remove the required value(s).

Comment: K..thks actully i have to make lots of chnges to remove that,so i was thinking of a short way..Lolzz ..thks

Comment: How would disabling some of the items, if it was possible, be easier?